Cannot access environment variable inside Github Action for React Application
I am trying to deploy my react app to EC2 using github action.
My application needs REACT_APP_BACKEND as the environment variable so I created a secret in the repo and used it inside the GITHUB ACTION. But, it seems the variable is not accessible here.
This is the workflow. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.
name: Deploy Frontend to EC2

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "deployment" ]

jobs:
  deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Deploy to EC2
      env:
        EC2_HOST: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}
        EC2_USER: ${{ secrets.EC2_USER }}
        EC2_KEY: ${{ secrets.EC2_KEY }}
        REACT_APP_BACKEND: ${{ secrets.BACKEND_URL }}
      run: |
        echo "${EC2_KEY}" > ec2-key.pem
        chmod 600 ec2-key.pem

        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ec2-key.pem $EC2_USER@$EC2_HOST << 'EOF'

          export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
          [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
          
          # Ensure the correct Node version is used
          nvm use 20.17.0

          cd /home/ubuntu/Portfolio/Portfolio-Frontend
  
          git pull origin deployment
          npm install

          npm run build
  
          sudo cp -r build/* /var/www/frontend

        EOF
        
        rm ec2-key.pem



REACT_APP_BACKEND is being defined in the GitHub Actions environment, but it's not being passed to the build step on the EC2 instance. The environment variable needs to be available during npm run build.
env:
    EC2_HOST: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}
    EC2_USER: ${{ secrets.EC2_USER }}
    EC2_KEY: ${{ secrets.EC2_KEY }}
    BACKEND_URL: ${{ secrets.BACKEND_URL }}
.
.
.
git pull origin deployment
npm install

# Inject the environment variable for React
echo "REACT_APP_BACKEND=${BACKEND_URL}" > .env

npm run build


This won't work beause the env defined in the github secret is not directly accessible inside the ssh block.
To make it work, we have to export the env to .env file and send it to ec2 using scp.
once it's done then we have access to the env inside the ssh block.
